# appcompat_v7.jar is missing

Tags: java, android

I am a fresh android developer. And when I create a new "Android Application Project", the minimum SDK is API7. The configuration is shown as below:
[image]

But after configuration, here is a problem that "appcompat_v7.jar" in Android Dependencies is missing. Someone can solve it?
[image]

Comment: Have you added `appcompat_v7` in your project's as library?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! This problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added `appcompat_v7` library project in your project's as library. 
From `Properties>Android Tab> Right panel in Add Library`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use Gradle ([Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) and the [build-tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) is the way to go), then in the *build.gradle* file specify it as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

of course you'll need to make sure that you've downloaded all the necessary files in the SDK Manager